# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sp500_stocks.csv'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a csv file to python, but this message keeps me getting forward.

The code I entered was

```
import errno
import os

raise FileNotFoundError(
    errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), 'sp500_stocks.csv')
```

I tried entering the path but with no luck. This was the syntax,

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/(taking out name for privacy)/Desktop/starter_files/sp500_stocks.csv')


stocks = pd.read_csv('sp500_stocks.csv')
type(stocks)
```

Is there something that I am missing? Thank you so much in advance.

I was trying to create my own weighted portfolio by batching API calls through all stocks and having few more indicators and formulas to compute number of shares to buy for each share.
The code I used to this is mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code given,I have no idea why this error happens but you can try move the file to your current working directory, using the relavant path to import this file.

```
# First move your file, then use
df = pd.read_csv('sp500_stocks.csv')
```